# Put someone on the same pedestal as another

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have recently got into a heated argument where I was told that I put them onto the same pedestal as another who had more experience in the field. It was clear from the context that they meant that my comparison was unfair but I think that this usage of pedestal in this sentence is incorrect. I did a quick google search which came back with some 17000 results, none of them are dictionary or thesaurus entries but coming from articles, blog entries or social media posts. In some cases they mean that one is or is not compared/accepted/respected/valued as high to/as another, while in others they use it to express that someone would aspire to be as praised and/or highly regarded as another if I managed to decode them right (eg. from the Guardian: The PM wants to be put on the same pedestal as Franklin D Roosevelt as he unveils £5bn capital projects.).

So my question is whether "to put someone on the same pedestal as someone" is a legitimate phrase and if yes what it means, what the correct usage is?

Comment: "put someone on a pedestal" is in most dictionaries ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-on-a-pedestal)). Putting on the same pedestal doesn't really alter the meaning.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is clear, you have done some research, and the question adheres reasonably well to the advice about questions given in https://english.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error   I therefore do not understand why it was downvoted - particularly as we encourage newcomers here and should not discourage them - so I have compensated.

Comment: Let's also note that referring to a pedestal often suggests the risks of lofty positioning: lack of freedom, unreasonable expectations. *Thanks, but don't put me on a pedestal.*

Comment: How big are the pedestals? And how many are there? How many people can stand on each?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to mention is the number of results of the Google search:

> I did a quick Google search which came back with some 17000 results,

No. It didn't. The actual number is given at the end of the final page of the results pages. In this case it is:

> *In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the **199** already displayed.*

Having glanced through them, the results are all valid and from reasonable sources.

It is not as common as "tar with the same brush/stick" but then the circumstances in which "the same pedestal" is said are not as common.

There is nothing wrong with "to put on the same pedestal as", and it is hard to think why there should be.

Comment: Indeed. It's simply extending a metaphor. And probably extending the pedestal to accommodate more people.

Answer (score 3):

Anna Calder, of the [Cambridge Language Collective](https://www.thecambridgelanguagecollective.com/), includes in a polished [article on Fernando Botero](https://www.thecambridgelanguagecollective.com/columns/deformation-as-reformation-fernando-botero):

> *Born in 1932 in Medellín, Colombia, Botero had his first exhibition
> in his early twenties. Inspired by a plethora of artists ranging from
> Velázquez, Rothko and Picasso, Botero refused to be categorised into
> one particular art school. Neither baroque, as was most popular in
> Colombia, nor abstract, the movement which was prominent whilst he
> lived in New York, Botero created his own style.
>
> His unusual take on
> canonical images led to great success and paved the way for his status
> as an iconic Latin American artist, placing him on the same pedestal
> as the likes of Gabriel García Márquez.*

I'd say this is a reference that strongly endorses (at least) acceptability of the extension to the familiar metaphor. (One might wonder about the suitability of the metaphor when applied to a painter, I suppose.)

The meaning is surely transparent: *to accord equal acclaim to; to rate [publicly or internally] as highly [in the designated field] as*. Here, with 'His unusual take' being a non-sentient agent, a paraphrase is 'His unusual take on canonical images led to great success and paved the way for his status as an iconic Latin American artist, giving him same stature as the likes of Gabriel García Márquez.'

Answer (score 2):

Putting someone on a pedestal suggests great admiration for great talent, not a workmanlike comparison of skills or capabilities in a particular field. Its implication of perfection allows for few if any competitors. I don’t know if that’s the situation or not.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! You seem to be exercising some curiosity about language use. Cool. I'm going to interpret the question through the lens of you being a manager to make the situation a little more concrete, but acknowledge it's not implied by the OP.

You say things like "legitimate phrase" and"correct usage".  That's very prescriptive language and thinking that we tend to get from our grammar teachers in school, as if there were language police. In informal conversation, we tend to police other's language and if we do, you might hear the moniker "[grammar Nazi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grammar_Nazi)" thrown around. I just wanted to raise the idea that there might be **in the context of an informal discussion, no actual thing as "legitimate phrase" or "correct usage" and suggest instead there is "common phrase" and "standard usage" instead**. This is advocating against thinking in terms of [language prescription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription).

**If you understood** that "being on the same pedestal" when your interlocutor was conveying the claim "I shouldn't be on the same pedestal" was figurative language for "I am not at their skill level and shouldn't be compared to be fair", **then the language achieved it's goal**. In fact, it should be noted that there is no rule against using figurative language or explicit analogies at all. It's the way we tend to communicate in English as native speakers to get the job done, though I understand that other languages might be more literal.

**Your question might be not "is it correct", but "is it standard"** because when dealing with language, linguists tend to differ from grammar marms by just using the question: how often is it done? does it sound right to our usage panel? One tool for doing that is Google's Ngram Viewer [("on the same pedestal")](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20the%20same%20pedestal&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3). As you can see, Google which searches through the books it has digitalized will tell you how often a phrase occurs relative to the corpus. In this case, there seems to be lots of usage for "on the same pedestal", though it has diminished in more modern times. If you survey those samples, you can see some of them are literal, and some of them are figurative, so it's hard to know what proportion are figurative.

According to [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20a%20pedestal), **to be "on a pedestal" is figurative language for "to think of someone as a perfect person with no faults : to admire someone greatly" which is how I would recognize it. So, the question can be honed to, does it makes sense to say "to put someone on the same pedestal as someone else"**, and I would say, why not? If you concede that you have an employee who you admire as being exemplary at their job, and your expectations are such that you expect another employee to meet the performance of the exemplar, then you are indeed wanting to place the latter on a pedestal as you do the former. Of course, that's all [loaded language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_language) in so far as it means you consider the former an exemplar since being good or bad at things has an emotional dimension for most people. Perhaps your perspective is that the latter employee isn't meeting the bare minimum of work performance behavioral objectives, in which case the conversation hinges on whether or not your standards are realistic.

So, **the question about the language "correctness" should be viewed as ancillary to the more important issue as a supervisor, and that is how to [frame your expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_(social_sciences))**. What's at stake is not whether someone is following the rules of language, (they seem to be communicating clearly, albeit figuratively), but rather the narrative at stake in the [Wittgensteinian language-game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_game_(philosophy)). Is reality that your expectations are unrealistic, or is that your employee's performance is subpar? Either way, the next step in the language-game is to have an amicable, honest conversation about expectations to try to build consensus preferably with the latter employee. Otherwise you give the former employee a justification for continuing to claim your expectations are unfair.

And that is how language works.

Answer (score 0):

You're technically right. "Put on the same pedestal" makes no sense using the original meaning of "put on a pedestal". But it seems as if enough people decided that "put on the same pedestal" has it's own completely new meaning, which is roughly "in the same league as".

"Put on a pedestal" originally meant to *uncritically* admire or respect. It's a bad thing to do. The implication is you wouldn't have the same opinion of them if you weren't so uncritical. A co-worker put on a pedestal probably isn't all that great, but everyone says they are. With that original meaning, "putting X on the same pedestal as Y" means that "X isn't as great as everyone says they are. In fact, their level of not-as-greatness is just as much as Y's level of that". It's nonsense and also not what your friend was trying to say.

But language changes. Sometimes it changes because someone didn't understand an idiom, used it incorrectly, and enough other equally ignorant people agreed on that new meaning.